# Cast int16_t memory to float

Tags: c++, memory, casting, floating-point

I have a function from an external source that returns an array of 2 uint16_t elements (which I cast to int).

I have already been able to cast these to one "big" int (`(i1 << 16) + i2`)

Now I need to be able to cast this to float, keeping the point value as is in memory.

Can anyone suggest a way or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding your problem correctly. You have a float f = 0.34  .....
Can you just not add "int ((i1 << 16) + i2)" to your float variable? That will preserve your value after decimal in float variable.

Comment: Or I should better ask you to clarify what do you mean by "Now I need to be able to cast this to float, keeping the point value as is in memory."?

Comment: Practical example: With i1=-13107 and i2=16708, could I just do float f = ((i1 << 16) + i2); to get the float 12.3? (Which it should be) Will it not automatically cast my int (which would be 1095027917) to float to have float f = 1095027917; ?
-- Addition: The both ints come from float from an external device

Comment: How is your int going to be "1095027917"? I am getting "-858963644".
And how do you get a float "12.3" with the example i1 and i2 you gave?

Comment: I must've switched i1 and i2... Apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a union:

```
union fltconv {
    float f;
    uint32_t i;
} u;
u.i = ((uint32_t) i1 << 16) | i2;
float f = u.f;
```

It's more explicit about what you're doing.  Bear in mind that this is *very* nonportable.

Comment: I think it is elegant, but the action is even more spooky, especially for the untrained eye, which will think `u` is a struct.

Comment: If I use an union, which indeed seems elegant, the way to port this in the future would probably be to adjust the uint32_t to the required number of bits (And underlying logic to convert it correctly?)

Comment: +1 because it's the only answer yet that does not break the strict aliasing rules. Casting to float might not survive the optimizer.

Comment: @Luther, it is as undefined as pointer punning due to the rule mandating that only the last field written should be read.

Comment: just wondering: can you *rely* on the overlap in memory of the union members? i.e. is it a feature? e.g. structs may have holes in them in memory, solved by things like `#pragma pack` iirc

Comment: why not union together a float and a struct of 2 uint16_t? saves you the shifting magic.

Comment: You could union together a float and a struct of 2 uint16_t, _but_ you have more problems - packing and byte order.  It would be even less portable than the union, as packing varies across compilers, and floating point typically varies across machines.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to keep very clear that you are messing around and use a memcpy:

```
float a;
int b;

memcpy(&a,&b,min(sizeof(a),sizeof(b)));
```

someone might encounter your code when you're long gone, in which case this will show there's something special happening *intentionally*.

Comment: For the record: you should consider byteordering as well, but that's more of an issue between the platforms talking to eachother. Google for `htons`, `htonl` and friends to get an idea.

Comment: +1 .. best method this one.  As a bonus every compiler I've used compiler will even optimise out the memcpy for you :D

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work?

```
uint32_t a = ....; // Contains your big int.
float b = *(float*)&a;
```

Of course that would require you to know int has the same size as float...

Comment: Although this works on my laptop, the endresult should work not only for this architecture, although I can, when the time comes to use the end device, check whether or not sizeof(float) == sizeof(int). However: Is there no other way of doing this?

Comment: Even, if you use memcpy, the whole re-interpretation will not make sense, unless float has exactly those 32 bits.

Comment: I include `sizeof()` more as a security measure (ha, stackoverflow!) than as a way of making sure the data comes in ok - byteordering hasn't been mentioned yet but will be the next hurdle...

Comment: I wasn't thinking about security really, but rather issues like: I've filled first 32-bits of 64-bit float. Hmm, that is not going to give the right value, is it? BTW: I guess we could agree float will not be smaller than those 32 bits.

Comment: yep, this is totally unreliable and 100% non-portable, but a stackoverflow can always be prevented.